expo-router issue TypeError: Cannot read property 'store' of undefined
Currently trying to integrate expo-router to my application and its not working properly. tried to fix all the dependencies and i cant say for sure why its not working. i have this component
`
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "expo-router";
export default function index() {
const [isLoggedIn, setisLoggedIn] = useState(false);
return (
<Redirect href={!isLoggedIn ? "/src/(routes)/onboarding": "/(tabs)/home"}/>
);
}`
enter image description here
above it is the structure of the application
and this is the error
This error is located at:
in Redirect (created by index)
in index
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
in SampleApp(RootComponent), js engine: hermes
enter image description here
anyone familiar with it?
these are the dependencies
enter image description here
tried updating the dependencies and its not working
Error 1 

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
